Countable system of differential equations
I'm interested in solving the following countably infinite system of ODEs
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}H_{n,k}\left(t\right)=\left(-p\right)nH_{n,k}\left(t\right)+\left(-q\right)nH_{n,k+1}\left(t\right)+pkH_{n+1,k-1}\left(t\right)+qkH_{n+1,k}\left(t\right),\qquad n,k=0,1,2,...,
\end{equation}
where $p,q>0$ are constants and we set $H_{n,-1}\left(t\right)\equiv 0$ ,
while the initial conditions are
$$H_{n,k}(0)=\begin{cases}
1 & n\geq1,k=0,\\
0 & \mathrm{otherwise.}
\end{cases}\qquad\qquad n,k=0,1,2,...$$
Following a similar (but simpler) problem, see [1], I set out to define the generating function
$$G(x,y,t):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}H_{n,k}\left(t\right)x^{n}y^{k},$$
where $x,y \in (-1,1)$.
Observe that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial t} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dt}H_{n,k}\left(t\right)x^{n}y^{k}, \\
x\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}nH_{n,k}\left(t\right)x^{n}y^{k}, \\
\frac{x}{y}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}nH_{n,k}\left(t\right)x^{n}y^{k-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=-1}^{\infty}nH_{n,k+1}\left(t\right)x^{n}y^{k}, \\
\frac{y}{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(yG\right) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(k+1\right)H_{n,k}\left(t\right)x^{n-1}y^{k+1} = \sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kH_{n+1,k-1}\left(t\right)x^{n}y^{k}, \\
\frac{y}{x}\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kH_{n,k}\left(t\right)x^{n-1}y^{k} = \sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kH_{n+1,k}\left(t\right)x^{n}y^{k}.
\end{align*}
Summing the first equation multiplied by $x^{n}y^{k}$ over $n,k=0,1,...$ yields
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}=-px\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}-q\frac{x}{y}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}+p\frac{y}{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(yG\right)+q\frac{y}{x}\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}-R\left(x,y\right),$$
where
$$R(x,y)=\left(-q\right)\frac{1}{y}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nH_{n,0}\left(t\right)x^{n}+p\frac{1}{xy}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kH_{0,k}\left(t\right)y^{k}+q\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kH_{0,k}\left(t\right)y^{k}.$$
The boundary terms correspond to:
\begin{align*}
-q\frac{1}{y}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nH_{n,0}(t)x^{n} & =-q\frac{x}{y}\left.\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}\right|_{y=0},\\
p\frac{1}{xy}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kH_{0,k}(t)y^{k} & =p\frac{1}{xy}\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(yG)\right|_{x=0},\\
q\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kH_{0,k}(t)y^{k} & =q\frac{1}{x}\left.\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}\right|_{x=0}.
\end{align*}
Hence the PDE is
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}=-px\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}-q\frac{x}{y}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}+p\frac{y}{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(yG\right)+q\frac{y}{x}\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}-q\frac{x}{y}\left.\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}\right|_{y=0}+p\frac{1}{xy}\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(yG)\right|_{x=0}+q\frac{1}{x}\left.\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}\right|_{x=0}$$
with the initial condition
$$G(x,y,0):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}H_{n,k}\left(0\right)x^{n}y^{k}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}H_{n,0}\left(0\right)x^{n}=\frac{x}{1-x}.$$
Though the the resulting PDE seems complicated (and maybe ill-posed? the boundary terms look suspicious), which suggests that either I have a mistake in my calculations or that this simply is not the right approach (though the approach itself using the generating functions seems elegant in my eyes). I have also considered using a laplace transform but that would yield a countably infinite system of algebraic equations (though linear). But since I have little knowledge about this topic, I have no yet done so. If you believe this would be a better approach, please share your views.
  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4279739/262202  


Laplace transform gives you a two-variable recurrence of functions of $s$. These can be approached in a similar way to what you have, i.e. a generating function solution, as seen here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206158/solving-recurrence-relation-in-2-variables
I imagine this will result in something simpler than that PDE you've got there, but I can't be sure. Or it might just give you the same PDE back again...
